# O365 - Unable to get Guest user email in SPPagecontextinfo

Tags: azure-active-directory, sharepoint-online

We have leveraged B2B to add 8 domains into one domain. Upon completion of adding other domain users as guest users, they are able to access the SharePoint site successfully. But the user logged in information like login name, Email address & user ID information is empty in SP page context info.

I have tried with a scenario like adding my organization account to the client tenant and verified. I'm able to get the context info about login name, email address & User ID.

Let me know if any one faced similar issue & any configurations to be made at source Azure AD/New Azure AD?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a look at the Asking Help page for help on posting a good question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
I think this question in its current form is a poor fit for the format of the web site, because there is no code here that we can help you improve. If you can, please edit the question to make it easier for someone to understand your problem.

Comment: If you want to use B2B to invite other domain users as gust users in your organization, you don't need to add their domains to yours.

Comment: And could you share the code snippet here, thanks!